# How do you say “Do you want a macaron"?

Tags: verbes, interrogative

How do you say *do you want a macaron* in French? I want to say it in a very simple way.

Comment: Hi! Please [edit](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/50094/edit) your question and indicate whether you're talking to a friend or a customer. Also, try to translate it and post the result in the question to show effort. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very simple sentence. But for questions in French, you have to decide whether you are using tu (familiar) or vous (polite).

Comment: Et pourquoi fermer cette question ? Pour quelle raison ? Il serait préférable de donner du temps à l'OP pour réagir. Je ne comprends pas du tout cette envie de cliquer sur le bouton "fermer" pour un oui et pour un non.

Answer (score 2):

There are [many ways](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/interrogation-directe) to ask a question in French so you have a [choice](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24622) (see more [content](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrogative) on the site). You can use a declarative sentence with rising intonation. This sentence will have a *subject-verb-complement* word order.

The subject will be a pronoun and depending on context, you might have to select either the 2nd person singular ([*tu*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tu#Pronom_personnel)) for people people you are closer to or the second person plural ([*vous*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vous)) which is typically the polite form when addressing one person, or when talking to many people. The verb will most likely be [*vouloir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vouloir#Verbe) and will agree with the singular or plural pronoun, depending. The noun serving as complement, [*macaron*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/macaron), is masculine, and the determiner is indefinite (and masculine, [*un*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un#Article_ind%C3%A9fini)) because we're most likely talking about a generic *macaron* and not a specfic one or exactly one. So you might end up with the following:

> *Tu veux un macaron ?* [with gradually rising intonation]
> *Vous voulez un macaron ?* [with gradually rising intonation]

Now you wanted something as simple as possible. So you might use a reduction/ellipsis to drop most of the words:

> ***Un macaron ?*** [with rising intonation]

If you have a box of these in your tands for instance, this is all you need. Plus in this case you don't need to confirm which pronoun to use and how the verb agrees.